# Python Motion Sensing

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I have 2 motion sensors in a doorway, my plan is to see if motion sensor 1 THEN 2 is triggered someone has entered, if 2 THEN 1 has been triggered then someone has exited. I already know how to program the motion sensors but how to i know if 1 THEN 2 has been triggered or vice versa.

Comment: How are the sensors connected to the raspberry? What have you tried and which part are you stuck at?

Comment: currently i am trying to make python react diffrently if sensor 1 is tripped and the 2 is or vice versa

Comment: So the problem isn’t gettong input from the sensors, but rather in which order they are triggered? If you keep a timestamp for when the sensor was triggered last you could have logic checking when other sensor was triggered. If ”just before” you can infer direction. If not, wait for other sensor. Show what code you already have.

Comment: Im still in the planning stage so no code yet. How do you suggest I go about this timestamps?